How to enable Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth) in my app
I have created an application on the LinkedIn Developers Platform and have requested certain products. Subsequently, I aim to connect to the API using the Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth).
I tried to Generating Access Token via the API but no luck. The API response with the error of "access_denied".
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}

Upon consulting the provided documentation, it states that 'Your application cannot access these APIs by default.'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext
Maybe I need to request for a partnership/extended access ?
I would appreciate it if anyone could provide the process for enabling the Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth) within my application.

I have the same issue. Any updates on this?
